# How to compare MCQS radio buttons input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am creating a quiz in reactjs and my data looks like

`Data.js`

```
{
category: "General Knowledge",
question: "Virgin Trains, Virgin Atlantic and Virgin Racing, are all companies owned by which famous entrepreneur? ",
answers: [
"Alan Sugar",
"Donald Trump",
"Bill Gates",
"Richard Branson"
]
},
```

Once the user submit the form how can I compare radio buttons input with another file where all the correct answers are stored ?

`Answers.js`

```
[ { "answer": 3 } ]
```

I am using ReactJs along with Redux

Comment: No-code question demands no-code answer. Assign index of `answer` as value of the option and then check with the number you have in `Answers.js`. Good luck.